# unable to see favicon at angular2 html page

Tags: html, angular, typescript, favicon

I can change my favIcon and use newIcon's by implementing snippet below succesfully. But I can only see one favIcon(skullIcon). I am not able to see other favIcons. I tried nearly 20 of them and only I can see them 1 of them. Do you think I have to modify my snippet to see all of them or I have to find a suitable favIcon in order to see it properly ? If yes, what I have to do to convert my icon to proper favIcon ?

Regards
Alper

```
 <head>

  <link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favIcon/test5.png" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In above example you are using png image file. however the favicon expects an icon image with .ico extension. Use below URL to convert your png image to icon.

http://www.xiconeditor.com

And try this : `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`

This works for me.

Comment: Hello Pratik. I followed every step that you defined but still I can not see the image. I wonder if I can resize it smaller or more smaller.    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon1.ico">

Comment: I also tried this. But still no progress 
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>

Comment: you gave missed the type="image/x-icon" in your above code. can you do that. Also if you require to resize it you can use the above link to do that.

Comment: and can you please share the screen shot of your screen if that doesn't work. Try keeping the icon in the same folder as index page to avoid confusion for the start and then you can move it later on.

Comment: Hello Pratik. It is same when I added type="image/x-icon". Here is my snapshot. Please let me know if you need more things. Regards https://snag.gy/dZ0MUn.jpg

Comment: by the way when I find another Icon. I can see it but this icon causes problems. I think my problem is icon not the code. What I need to do to get a proper favIcon ? I guess I can not get a proper one by xiconeditor.

Comment: if its the image issue then u can use xicon editor link to change it. coz this is straight forward.